# How to delete a temporary object on a child managed object context?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a CodeData model [Phone]<<--->>[Forwarding].  So the Phone object has a Forwardings set, and vice versa.

I have a list of Phones and want to add one of them to a new Forwarding.

In the `ForwardingViewController` I do:

```
// Create a new managed object context; set its parent to the fetched results controller's context.
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[managedObjectContext setParentContext:[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
self.forwarding = (ForwardingData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Forwarding"
```

So this creates a child MOC and a now temporary Forwarding.

Then I pass `self->forwarding` to my `PhonesViewController` which shows all Phones (in a table).  This view controller is simply navigation-pushed.

When the user taps on one of the Phones in the table I do:

```
[self.forwarding addPhonesObject:phone];
```

The `addPhonesObject` is a CoreData generated accessor.

Now, when the user is back at the `ForwardingViewController` and taps the Cancel button (because he decides he does not want to create a new Forwarding after all), it is dismissed, which cleans up this child `managedObjectContext` and also `self.forwarding`.

After doing the above, I get a database error (Cocoa error 1550).  When trying to understand the console output, my guess is that the Forwarding was indeed deleted, but that the Phone object (which of course is still there), now has a null reference to this deleted Forwarding.

My question.  How should I handle this case correctly: Having a temporary object created on a child MOC, link it to another object (on the parent MOC), and then delete this temporary object again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the actual error you are getting?

From your description, I am guessing that your `PhonesViewController` is listing phones from a different `NSManagedObjectContext` than the one that you created the `ForwardingData` entity from.  This violates the relationship rule with Core Data.  The rule is simple, to create a relationship between two entities they must both be from the same `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

I question why you are creating a temporary `NSManagedObjectContext` in this situation.  Since you are retaining the `ForwardingData` entity and you know when you are being cancelled, it seems cleaner to just delete the temporary entity when cancel is pressed instead of standing up another `NSManagedObjectContext`.

### Update

If you need to use the child (per your comment), then you should change your `PhonesViewController` to accept a `NSManagedObjectContext` via dependency injection.  Then you can send it the same `NSManagedObjectContext` instance as the one you used to create the new entity.  With that change everything will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Ah, that must be my problem: working with two different MOCs.  And good idea to simplify and just delete the `ForwardingData` object on cancel (I got this construction from Apple doc or sample).

Comment: Apple examples are great at showing you what you **can** do, not so great at showing you what you **should** do.

Comment: It works well without the child MOC.  Thanks a lot!  But why do you think using a child MOC is not a good idea [here]?  There is a side effect of using one MOC: An empty item appears on the Forwardings table as the new Forwarding view controller slides up from below; of course because the new Forwarding is created in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Another problem without child MOC is that the data may be updated at the same time (pulled from server); I just saw a Cocoa error 1560 because of this, while creating a new forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was already looking at passing in the MOC.